# curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080 Connection refused

Tags: command-line, docker, curl, localhost

I am trying to use this command to see the running status of my port, but I am getting this error in a loop. 
Kindlly help!

Comment: The response is clearly telling you the status of the port. It's closed.

Comment: The port 8080 is closed, that's why you are getting error.  If you want to check the status of port, you could use netstat command

Comment: can you tell me how to use this command

Comment: See `man netstat` for complete instructions on how to use the command. See also the many netstat tutorials available online. We are happy to answer questions, but we are not going to re-create those many resources for you.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, port 8080 is not open on the host in question.
To see if something is listening on a certain port or if it's open at all, you can use `netstat -tlpen | grep 8080` or `nc -vz [host] [port]`

Comment: can u tell me how to use this command

Comment: I have the same issue, and here is my output from netstat:


tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      0          665011     -

Answer (score 1):

If, for whatever reason, you're using WSL2 to curl a server running within your local windows host, you will need to specify the windows host IP address.

`ipconfig` to get your windows host IP. E.g.,

`192.168.420.69`

Then curl using your address within WSL2. E.g.,

`curl 192.168.420.69:8080`

Or, more simply, curl from the same environment.